# Xamarin Android correct Asynchronous way

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, xamarin.android

i am new on xamarin android apps.I want to build an app and i have read that connections with database or the execution of queries should happen asynchronously from the main thread otherwise the UIthread will may collapse.I have found 2 ways to do that:

First way:

```
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
Uri uri = new Uri("http://192.168.2.8/CreateUsername.php");
NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
parameters.Add("Name", txtname.text);
client.UploadValuesCompleted += Client_UploadValuesCompleted;
client.UploadValuesAsync(uri,parameters); ---> is this gonna create a new thread and run asynchronously???
```

(here i found the first way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jF3D__ibrx8 )

SecondWay:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/web_services/consuming_services/call_a_rest_web_service/

Both ways are correct?both of ways are gonna create a new thread and run asynchronously?Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both examples are ok but I'd usually trust the official documentation by Xamarin first. What might confuse you with the first example is the lack of await keyword when calling the `UploadValuesAsync` method. Here's what actually happens:

1. Call to UploadValuesAsync is made from the UI thread.
2. UI thread blocks until the method returns because it's running synchronously.
3. However, the method returns very quickly because it launches the upload process asynchronously on another thread internally and doesn't wait for the process to complete.
4. When the whole upload process is finished, `Client_UploadValuesCompleted` will be called.

As you can see on the WebClient.UploadValuesAsync page on MSDN, it states that:

> These methods do not block the calling thread.

Also, when looking at the [source code for UploadValuesAsync](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/webclient.cs,2486), you'll notice the following attribute defined on top:

```
[HostProtection(ExternalThreading=true)]
```

which means the following:

> Code that exposes external threading creates or manipulates threads other than its own, which might be harmful to the host.

To sum it up, the upload process is handled on another background thread but otherwise, your code will run synchronously. There's a bit more asynchronicity going on in Xamarin's sample.